# Error while connecting to impala with JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, impala

I am trying to connect from Java program to impala using the below driver

> com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver

but I am getting a run time exception while doing so, below is the stack-trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V6
at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.openSession(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HS2Client.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hivecommon.api.HiveServer2ClientFactory.createClient(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
```

I am also attaching the code below for reference

```
 Class.forName("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver");
    Connection connection = null;
    connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:impala://IP:21050/default;user=foo;password=bar") ;
    Statement statement = null;
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select count(*) from table");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(0));

    }
```

Comment: can you please mention your CDH version,Hive and impala?

Comment: Impala 0.2, CDH 5.4, hive 0.13

Comment: can you check the jar versions you using as dependency

Comment: please remove the correct IP address before someone mess all your database

Comment: Thanks for the concern Paizo : its not my actual IP

Comment: @Paizo one question if you do not mind: the OP can remove the database IP from the question but we can still see in the edit history, am I right? There is any way that can be permanently deleted from the history? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry @RCaetano but I have no idea